# SQL where in using parameter

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-4.0

I am trying to get a "where in" to work using a parameter in sql.

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE(name IN (@names))
```

So I execute the SQL in sqlmanager, and enters 'Name1', 'Name2' in @name value, when i get asked for it. This way, query returns 0 rows. But if i change the SQL to:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE(name IN ('Name1','Name2'))
```

It works.

What is the trick to make it work?

This post solved it for me: [Link to post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/337752/1425580) Thanks for all the responses :)

Comment: Quick quiz - name *any* programming language that, if you pass a single parameter, it will inspect the interior of that parameter, spot the comma, split on the comma, and treat everything from then on as if multiple parameters were provided?

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this..

```
Declare @names varchar(150)
Set @names = '''Name1'',''Name2'''
Declare @str varchar(max) 
set @str = 'SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE(name IN ('+@names+'))'
Execute(@str)
```

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL injection if the names list includes [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Sql Injection is not possible because here @names is Parameter in Sql stored procedure.

Comment: Just because `@names` is a parameter doesn't magically protect you from SQL injection if you then construct a non parameterised dynamic SQL query through string concatenation and execute it.